# How to refresh a div in a for each loop using ajax?

Tags: ajax

I tried using this `("#refresh").load(document.URL + "#refresh")` but it only works for 1 data in a for each loop, I was wondering if there is a way like to click a button and change its value from "Read" to Unread"

view.php

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-mar' data-id='{{ $complaint->uniquekey }}' aria-hidden='true' >
 <div class="ref{{ $complaint->id }}" id="refresh">
  {{ $complaint->status == 'unread' ? 'Read' : 'Unread' }}
 </div>
</button>
```

this is my script

```
$(document).on("click",'.btn-mar', function(t) {
    t.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.data('id');
    var refresh = $("#refresh").attr('class');
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('complaints.mar') }}',
        method:"POST",
        data: {uniquekey:id},
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert(id);
        },
        success: function(t) {
            $(refresh).attr('class').load(document.URL + refresh);
        },
        error: function(t) {
            alert("Internal Server Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so instead of using a div for me to use, I use this

```
if($('#'+id).html()=="Unread"){
  $('#'+id).html('Read');
}
else{
  $('#'+id).html('Unread');
}
```

and then change the

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-mar' data-id='{{ $complaint->uniquekey }}' aria-hidden='true' >
 <div class="ref{{ $complaint->id }}" id="refresh">
  {{ $complaint->status == 'unread' ? 'Read' : 'Unread' }}
 </div>
</button>
```

To

```
<button type='button' id="{{ $complaint->uniquekey }}" class='btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-mar' data-id='{{ $complaint->uniquekey }}' aria-hidden='true' >
     {{ $complaint->status }}
</button>
```